# Parsing string using PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP & want to parse given string:
Let say

```
$str = '<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/W-WKYIgGBbU&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param><param 
name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/W-WKYIgGBbU&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" width="100" height="100"></embed>
</object>';
```

and I just need

```
$output = '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/W-WKYIgGBbU&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true" width="100" height="100"></embed>';
```

**and set height and width to my custom value let say $width = 30 and $height = 40.**

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
preg_match("/<embed.*\/embed>/mi",$str,$matches);
$output = preg_replace(array('/width="\d+"/i','/height="\d+"/i'),array('width="30"','height="40"'),$matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it really works & it's excellent..............
1000s of thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are always going to get well formed html, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse HTML using Tidy and SimpleXML:

1. Clean HTML with [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php)
2. Find and modify <embed> tag with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this

```
<?php

$string = '<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/W-WKYIgGBbU&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/W-WKYIgGBbU&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100" height="100"></embed></object>';
$pattern = '/.*src="(.*?)".*/';
$replacement = '<embed src="\\1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100" height="100"></embed>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

?>
```